# Using securesocial module in play

Tags: java, playframework, securesocial

I get the following error the moment I add the @With (SecureSocial.class) to protect one of the controller classes. Not sure why, since I do have it working in another project which has more classes.

```
Oops: VerifyError
An unexpected error occured caused by exception VerifyError: Bad return type in method controllers.securesocial.SecureSocial.loadCurrentUser()Lsecuresocial/provider/SocialUser; at offset 53
    play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
            at play.Invoker$Invocation.onException(Invoker.java:232)
            at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:273)
            at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type in method controllers.securesocial.SecureSocial.lo
    adCurrentUser()Lsecuresocial/provider/SocialUser; at offset 53
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808)
            at play.utils.JavaWithCaching.findAllAnnotatedMethods(Java.java:500)
            at play.utils.JavaWithCaching.findAllAnnotatedMethods(Java.java:507)
            at play.utils.JavaWithCaching.findAllAnnotatedMethods(Java.java:470)
            at play.utils.Java.findAllAnnotatedMethods(Java.java:255)
            at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.handleFinallies(ActionInvoker.java:382)
            at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:255)
            ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0):

A VerifyError happens when the code you run is compiled against a different version than the one the JVM loads when executing the code.

How does your dependencies.yml look like? Have you run play deps in this machine?

Comment: Play version is 1.2.3# Application dependencies

require:
    - play -> securesocial 0.2.4
    - play

Comment: Try executing "play clean" and also remove the /.ivy2/cache/play/securesocial directory under your home.  Then run play deps again and execute the app.

Comment: Tried that. In fact removed the entire .ivy2 directory, Still did not help.

Comment: Tried the same in linux and works without any problem. Will try reinstalling the latest jvm on windows.